# Can I use an update-timestamp field to enable High Water Mark Change Detection in Azure Search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

My database is SQL Server 2012 in an Azure VM.  I'm pushing data into an Azure Search instance.  The data comes from an SQL View, so I can't use SQL Integrated Change Tracking.  Instead, I'd like to use the High Water Mark Change Detection Policy, as outlined in [Microsoft's document describing how to connect Azure Search to SQL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers-2015-02-28/).  My data doesn't have a row version, which is the technique used as an example, but it does have an update-timestamp, which is maintained when the record is created or updated.  Can I use this field for High Water Mark Change Detection?

Answer (score 0):

yes, any column with high water mark semantics will work. Thanks for using Azure Search!